# Running Cucumber.js scenarios in parallel with Webdriver.io and Browserstack Automate

Tags: selenium, cucumber, cucumberjs, webdriver-io, browserstack

I'm currently attempting to run Cucumber.js scenarios in parallel against multiple browsers, using Webdriver.io's test runner and Browserstack Automate. I’ve specified capabilities in the test runner’s config for each browser and OS we’d like to test against. There is one Webdriver.io config file set up to execute the test run against Browserstack Automate.

I’d like to execute the test run once and have every scenario running concurrently in a separate Browserstack VM- for example, running the first test across Chrome, Firefox, IE and Safari, at the same time that the second test is running against the same platforms:

[Parallel execution of scenarios per VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq9A8.png)

Unfortunately it seems that the following happens instead:

[Serial execution of scenarios per VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbIRe.png)

- Browserstack runs all of the features and scenarios serially in a VM for each specified capability, instead of running one test per VM
- Placing individual scenarios into separate feature files has no
  effect- features (and therefore scenarios) are still executed serially on each VM

Is it possible to run each scenario concurrently, in separate Browserstack VMs?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is not with BrowserStack, but the way you are launching your tests in parallel. BrowserStack will assign a remote machine to the test, based on how it receives the request.

Since you are using WebdriverIO, you can use the '[multiremote](http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/multiremote.html)' feature to run your tests in parallel as follows:

```
var browser = webdriverio.multiremote({
    myChromeBrowser: {
        desiredCapabilities: {
            browserName: 'chrome'
        }
    },
    myFirefoxBrowser: {
        desiredCapabilities: {
            browserName: 'firefox'
        }
    }
});
```

To use this 'multiremote' feature of BrowserStack, you can have a look at this [sample script](https://gist.github.com/UmangSardesai/c6b6d1f48ffb65b216f9).

Additionally, would recommend dropping an email to support@browserstack.com for further help.

---

**UPDATE:**
WebDriverIO v4.0 now inherently supports parallel testing. You can run in parallel on different browser and OS combinations by specifying multiple sets of capabilities as given below:

```
user: process.env.BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME,
key: process.env.BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY,

maxInstances: 10,

capabilities: [{
     os: 'OS X',
     os_version: 'Yosemite',
     browser: 'firefox',
     browser_version: '44',
     name: 'Parallel Tests',
     build: 'Sample WebDriverIO tests',
 },    
 {
     os: 'Windows',
     os_version: '10',
     browser: 'Chrome',
     browser_version: '44',
     name: 'Parallel Tests',
     build: 'Sample WebDriverIO tests'
 }]
```

You refer the sample project [here](https://github.com/browserstack/webdriverio-browserstack) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd looked at Multiremote before on the WebdriverIO site and it appears to be designed for setting up multiple browsers to interact with each other, as opposed to being intended for true parallel test runs. As the documentation states:

"Note: Multiremote is not meant to execute all your tests in parallel. It should help you to coordinate more than one browser for sophisticated integration tests."